# Jquery cookies problem

Tags: jquery

I'm using cookie plugin with jquery. I set cookie like `$.cookie('key','value')`. In firebug I can see that the cookie is set but `console.log($.cookie('key'))` returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I just tried $.cookie('name','User'); console.log($.cookie('name')); In firebug console. They are working fine. Just check casing of your key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding more parameters, only for testing:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com' });
```

To verify the value of the cookie, you can also use the Web Developer Extension, they have an option for view cookies.

Comment: $.cookie('key','value', {path : '/'}); did the trick. I noticed that the cookie was set for the current page only